# join method of select in column list

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

this is an 11g question, but I guess this is version agnostic.

I have this simple select:

```
create table tab_a (id number);
create table tab_b (id number);
create table tab_c (id number);

select 
    a.id,b.id,(select c.id from tab_c c where c.id = a.id) 
from 
    tab_a a join tab_b b on a.id = b.id;
```

Which gives me such a plan:

```
SELECT LPAD(' ',depth)||OPERATION||'_'||OPTIONS||' '||OBJECT_NAME plan
FROM v$sql_plan
WHERE plan_hash_value = 2530031923
order by id;
```

> ```
> SELECT STATEMENT_ 
>  TABLE ACCESS_FULL TAB_C
>  HASH JOIN_ 
>   TABLE ACCESS_FULL TAB_A
>   TABLE ACCESS_FULL TAB_B
> ```

My question now please is: How is `TAB_C` joined to the result of the hash join of `TAB_A` and `TAB_B`? Is it accessed in a nested loop once for each result of the hash join? Is it a hash join with `TAB_C` as the driving table? Sort-merge?Anything totally different? Can there be different join methods to `TAB_C` behind this plan or is it always the same one?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should use a bit more recent technik to inspect the execution plan, e.g. DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY`

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'sqlx' into   plan_table  FOR
select 
    a.id,b.id,(select c.id from tab_c c where c.id = a.id) 
from 
    tab_a a join tab_b b on a.id = b.id;


SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'sqlx','ALL'));    

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |   100 |  2600 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL | TAB_C |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |  HASH JOIN         |       |   100 |  2600 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB_A |   100 |  1300 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB_B |   100 |  1300 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("C"."ID"=:B1)
   2 - access("A"."ID"="B"."ID")
```

This gives you the information how the `TAB_C` is accessed. You see in *Predicate Information* for line 1 `filter("C"."ID"=:B1)`.

In other word you will **full scan the table for each `ID`** joined between the tables A and B. Which is of course not desired.

If you do not trust this simple run the  query and *gather the plan statistics*

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */
    a.id,b.id,(select c.id from tab_c c where c.id = a.id) 
from 
    tab_a a join tab_b b on a.id = b.id;  

---
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST')); 

SQL_ID  4m4a1cp4gyjkv, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */     a.id,b.id,(select c.id from 
tab_c c where c.id = a.id)  from      tab_a a join tab_b b on a.id = 
b.id

Plan hash value: 2606630813

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |      1 |        |    100 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL | TAB_C |    100 |      1 |    100 |00:00:00.01 |     700 |       |       |          |
|*  2 |  HASH JOIN         |       |      1 |    100 |    100 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |  1517K|  1517K| 1256K (0)|
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB_A |      1 |    100 |    100 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB_B |      1 |    100 |    100 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("C"."ID"=:B1)
   2 - access("A"."ID"="B"."ID")
```

In the line 1 you see starts = 100, meaning 100 time the `FULL SCAN` was initiated.

**Caution** - the execution plan may change dependent of the table statistics, optimizer setting or Oracle version (e.g. Oracle can *rewrite* the subquery and use a join).

This is only an example with dummy tables on 11.2.
But you should get the impression how to observe the behaviour of Oracle and to decide if you need an additional index or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now that this kind of plan represents a nested loop with TAB_C inside. You showed me exactly what I wanted to know and more! Thank you very much and kind regards!